# How to make Geiser send the output to REPL buffer instead of echo area?

Tags: scheme

I am running Emacs25 with Geiser (latest version from MELPA, 20180128.1821) and Guile (version 2.2, Debian package). So far it works fine, but when I evaluate a sexp, it will print the result to Emacs' echo area instead of in the REPL buffer. Is there a way to change this behavior? I'd like to be able to scroll through long output, copy parts of it, etc.

I tried looking into the configuration menus, but found nothing that seemed to be related to that.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: 1. How are you evaluating the sexp? 2. You can print the result to the buffer you want - see (elisp) node [Output Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Streams.html). Or you can insert it into a buffer using `insert`.

Comment: I evaluate with C-x C-e (which by default is bound to "eval sexp before point" in Geiser). It seems that the natural thing to do would be to send the output to the REPL, and not  to some other buffer.

Comment: What's "the REPL buffer"? Perhaps you mean something like buffer `*scratch*`. In any case, to insert the result in the **current** buffer (where the sexp is that you evaluate), just use `C-u C-x C-e`. `C-h k C-x C-e` tells you this.

Comment: By REPL buffer I mean the buffer where Geiser runs the Guile REPL (the usual way is to have one buffer with the code and one where the REPL is; the second is interactive).

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible. Based on Geiser doc (https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_4.html):

> For all the commands above, the result of the evaluation is displayed
> in the minibuffer, unless it causes a (Scheme-side) error