# Capturing output scheme when executing a code block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, doom, scheme

I cannot find a way to intercept the output when I evaluate a scheme code block as below (I'm trying with Geiser):

```
#+NAME: test
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :session sicp :lexical t :results output verbatim replace
(define a (list 2 3 4))
(set-car! a 9)
a
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test
: Geiser Interpreter produced no output
```

This seems to not be possible with Geiser at all as answered on [this other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64474/5209)

Is there's another scheme mode that can support my use case?

I just want to get the output from a scheme REPL as in:

```
#+NAME: test
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :session sicp :lexical t :results output verbatim replace
(define a (list 2 3 4))
(set-car! a 9)
a
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test
(9 3 4)
```

The software versions I'm using are:

- GNU Emacs 28.1
- Doom 3.0-dev (can't find a better version than the SHA1 commit `7a30582505`)
- org 9.6
- chez scheme 9.5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the path of `ob-scheme.el`, for me that is

```
~/.emacs.d/.local/straight/repos/org/lisp/ob-scheme.el
```

and then in function `org-babel-scheme-execute-with-geiser`, change `geiser-eval-region` to `geiser-eval-region/wait`, which will wait for the evaluation to finish

```
        ;;(let ((ret (geiser-eval-region (point-min) (point-max))))
        (let ((ret (geiser-eval-region/wait (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Finally, press `C-M-x` to eval the function, and the Geiser worked.

Comment: This did work for me--the one packaged with Homebrew emacs plus was compiled as `ob-scheme.elc`. Nevertheless, replacing `geiser-eval-region` with `geiser-eval-region/wait` did the trick!

Comment: The patched version from https://gitlab.com/emacs-geiser/guile/-/issues/21 is now also available through Doom emacs and it works correctly.

Comment: For macOS Homebrew installations of Emacs, where would `ob-scheme.el` be installed?  Searching my home directory I can see:

`$HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs-plus@29--git/lisp/org/ob-scheme.el`

and

`$HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs--git/lisp/org/ob-scheme.el`

Comment: Found it at `/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-plus@28/28.2/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/org`

Answer (score 0):

Either use `:results value`, *not* `:results output`, in the code block header, or keep `:results output` and use `(princ a)` rather than `a` (or whatever the equivalent of Elisp's `princ` is in Scheme).

Comment: With Geiser this doesn't work. I'm not sure if there's another mode I should use to connect org with a scheme REPL.
Using `:results value` I don't get anything from Geiser (the result is left empty in the `org` file).
`(printc a)` also doesn't produce any output that can be captured by Geiser. I've also tried `(printf "a = ~d/n" a)` with similar, unsuccesfull, results.